# Python type-hints where only the first item is None

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am implementing a priority queue class in Python using a binary heap, which has a attribute that stores the binary tree. In my implementation, I'm using 1-indexing because it has the nice property that I can use lists (say, the list is called `heap`) and the children of `heap[i]` are exactly `heap[2*i]` and `heap[2*i+1]`, which are nice.

I am padding the heap attribute with an initial inaccessible `None` to facilitate this 1-indexed array.

Below is the implementation I've got (minimal working example):

```py
Item = TypeVar("Item")

class PriorityQueue(Generic[Item]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._heap: list[Optional[Item]] = [None]
        # ...
```

but then this runs into problems at

```py
    def dequeue(self) -> Item:
        # ...
        return item_dequeued
```

This method returns an item from the end of the heap list, which we can guarantee to be of the type `Item` (not `None`). However, MyPy was like

```
mypy: error
return-value - Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[int]", expected "int")
```

But in the type-hint for the method I didn't really want to change the return type to `Optional[Item]` because it less accurately reflects the behaviour of the method.

What's the correct way to type-hint all this?

Thank in advance!

I have a few ideas in mind:

1. Pad the list with an `Item` instead. But this makes the code less obvious, hiding the fact that the first item in a dummy.
2. ```py
   dummy_item = -1
   self._heap = [dummy_item] # now mypy can correctly guess the type of _heap
   ```

   but this feels wrong to me somehow.
3. Put in `# type: ignore[return-value]` (possibly last resort?)

I'm looking for the most correct way to do this, following the guidelines of mypy or just more being pythonic in general.

Comment: You are only storing a dummy item to simulate an array with 1-based indexing. Since the actual value doesn't matter, just store an int. `None` doesn't serve any *semantic* purpose here, because its presence is entirely opaque to the *user* of `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: (Regarding idea 1: using -1 as a sentinel for type `int` is no more arbitrary than using `None` as a sentinel for type `Optional[int]`. The idea to use a single dedicated type to indicate the absence of a value of any type is a very dynamic-typing idea; compare Haskell's approach of having a separate `Nothing :: a` value for every type `Maybe a`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer predates the change from `Item` being an alias for `int` to a type variable for a generic queue. For the generic class, I would be even more inclined to give up on 1-based indexing, because now you either use the too-loose type `list[Optional[Item]]` to describe the heap, or you make the user
responsible for providing an appropriate `Item` value for queue-specific internal purposes.)

---

`None` serves no semantic purpose here, so using it just complicates your typing. Any arbitrary integer would work just as well, because it's an internal implementation detail of your class.

```
class PriorityQueue:
    Item: TypeAlias = int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._heap: list[PriorityQueue.Item] = [0]
        # ...
```

If you really want, you can use a class "constant" to emphasize its actual value.

```
class PriorityQueue:
    Item: TypeAlias = int
    _SHIM: ClassVar[Item] = 0

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._heap: list[PriorityQueue.Item] = [PriorityQueue._SHIM]
        # ...
```

---

Or, don't worry about 1-based indexing. With 0-based indexing, the arithmetic works out to be parent `i` has children `2*i + 1` and `2*i + 2`;  1-based indexing only saves you an addition when specifically traversing to the left, and nobody *outside* `PriorityQueue` needs to know or care about the indexing. (For all they know, you aren't using an array at all, and have an explicit tree built from nodes like

```
class HeapNode(Generic[Item]):
    value: Item
    left: HeapNode[Item]
    right: HeapNode[Item]
```

)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I apologise for abruptly changing my code in the question. I didn't see your response when I altered it. The other main reason for using 1-based indexing was because going backwards (up the tree) is just a right shift by 1. After reading your insightful response, I've being convinced that 0-based indexing is the way to go. I'll go fix up my maths.

Comment: Up the tree is just `(i-1)//2` now, which is admittedly not *as* tidy, but you were never going to get all three operations (up, down-left, down-right) to be simple, so you may as well pick the set that doesn't disrupt other parts of the class design.

Comment: No worries about the change; generic is better, and makes the question less trivial :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading you correctly, you have a method that returns, in principle, `Optional[Item]`, but you know (due to some logic that the type-checker can't understand) that this method will *always* return `Item`. The best way to handle that is with an `assert`.

```
def dequeue(self) -> Item:
    # ...
    assert item_dequeued is not None, "Internal error! Heap was empty!"
    return item_dequeued
```

Mypy is clever. It knows that, after running this assertion, if the code hasn't thrown an exception, then `item_dequeued` must not be of type `None`, and hence (by process of elimination) must be of type `Item`.

As a bonus, if your assumption turns out to be wrong and `dequeue` returns `None`, then `dequeue` fails immediately with a nice error message of your own design, explaining the problem, as opposed to failing with a spurious `NoneType has no operation blah` somewhere down the line in your code.

Comment: This is the right way, but I'm not sure an `AssertionError` is the correct error type. Most other collections raise an `IndexError` when `pop` is called and it's empty

Comment: If this is an error that OP expects to see *ever*, then I agree: `IndexError` would make far more sense. My read of the OP's question was that the `None` case literally should not occur (hence, is a bug in the library if it ever does), and in that case I think `AssertionError` is appropriate.

Comment: @silvio Thank you for your quick response! My code already raises `IndexError` if it fails `self.is_empty()` (it was ommited in `# ...`), so I believe `AssertionError` is very appropriate here, because as you said, something very wrong must've happened for that assertion to fail!

Comment: Assertions can be disabled at runtime, so an explicit check like `if item_dequeue is None: raise ValueError(...)` would be better. (Not as good as using a homogenous list type in the first place, but better.)