# Typing class attributes with default value None - best practices?

Tags: python, python-2.7, typing, pylance, pyright

I am trying to introduce type hints to legacy Python 2.7 code. Many classes declare class attributes with a default value of `None` (to avoid mutable defaults) and then assign the value in the constructor, like so:

```py
class Myclass(object):
    _myList = None  # Description
    _myList2 = None  # Description
    _myList3 = None  # Description
    
    def __init__(self, inList=None):
        self._myList = inList or []
        self._myList2 = []
    
    def show(self):
        print(self._myList)
        print(self._myList2)
        print(self._myList3)
```

For the example below, I could not come up with a way that correctly infers `_myList` and `_myList2` and does not give errors.

```py
from typing import Optional, List

class Myclass(object):
    _myList = None  # type: Optional[List]  # T1
    _myList2 = None  # type: Optional[List]  # T2
    _myList3 = None  # type: Optional[List]  # T3
    
    def __init__(self, inList=None):
        # type: (Optional[List]) -> None   # T4
        self._myList = inList or []  # type: List  # T5
        self._myList2 = []  # type: List  # T6
    
    def show(self):
        print(self._myList)
        print(self._myList2)
        print(self._myList3)
```

Pyright gives errors on lines T1 and T2 in this example (`Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to declared type "List[Unknown]"`). They remain if the type hints on lines T1-T3 are removed.

Removing the type hints from lines T5 and T6 clears the errors, but the types in `show(self)` are not inferred to be `List` anymore, despite being assigned in the constructor. This is a problem because other code assumes that the fields are not `None`.

What is the correct way to add type hints in cases like this? Is there a way that it can be done without changing the class structure?

I have looked at questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62723766/how-to-get-type-hints-for-an-objects-attributes) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75824141/python-type-hints-where-only-the-first-item-is-none) but found no good answer. Explanations about the standard in Python 3 are welcome, but please ensure compatibility with Python 2.7.

Comment: Please include the actual error that `pyright` generated, though at a casual glance you are trying to redefine instance attribute to `List` from a class attribute that was `Optional[List]` where this is considered incompatible by pyright.

Comment: I added the errors and clarified that my problem is not being able to eliminate the errors while keeping the correct type inference.

Comment: Change `T5` and `T6` to `Optional[List]` to match with `T1` and `T2` was the essence of my original advice. Having what are essentially mismatched types is a good way to fail type hinting checks (`T1` and `T5` shares the same name assignment, likewise `T2` and `T6`). Moreover, [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3628#issuecomment-1169089086) on [microsoft/pyright#3628](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3628) essentially confirms my hunch when I decided to search using `"pyright" instance attribute vs class attribute`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link that my search didn't turn up. The problem is that `T1` and `T2` are only for documentation, and using `Optional[List]` would cause a lot of errors in other parts of the code. The type should really be `List`. I posted an answer.

Comment: Yeah, only you know what you are really after and writing your own answer is - especially when the intention is to not care at all about class attributes, though `pyright` cannot guard against usage of `del myclass_inst._myList` which would force the fallback resolution of that deleted attribute to `Myclass._myList` (Python typing does not guard against _all_ of the foundation's (being the language itself) misfeatures).

Answer (score 0):

I could only find two solutions:

1. Avoid the `= None` assignment.
2. Use the `Optional` type and check for `is not None` explicitly in every function.

```py
class Myclass(object):
    _myList = None  # type: Optional[List]

    def __init__(self, inList=None):
        # type: (Optional[List]) -> None
        self._myList = inList or []

    def show(self):
        assert(self._myList is not None)
        print(self._myList)
```

I have tried forcing the `None` assignment to be ignored, but you cannot rely on the type checker to follow this. It will not work reliably.

```py
class Myclass(object):
    _myList = None  # type: ignore
    
    def __init__(self, inList=None):
        # type: (Optional[List]) -> None
        self._myList = inList or []  # type: List
    
    def show(self):
        print(self._myList)
```

Once again, this is only for legacy code that has to remain compatible with Python 2. In Python 3, [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) make this much more readable.